# Order of output varies with runs

Tags: python, tuples, yield

I've got a simple function:

```
def foo(inp):
    i = 0
    while (i < len(inp)):
        yield {i,inp[i]}
        i = i+1

for x in foo(("a", "b", "c")):
    print(x)
```

which I expect to print

```
{0, 'a'}
{1, 'b'}
{2, 'c'}
```

but it **sometimes** prints

```
{0, 'a'}
{1, 'b'}
{'c', 2}
```

Why are the last tuple's members swapped?

To make it stranger, adding "d" to the input list, I see three different outputs.  Either all outputs are in order, I get only `{'d',3)` swapped, or I get both `{'c',2)` and `{'d',3)` swapped

> sys.version: 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC
>   v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: As stated in the docs, set sare [Unordered collections of unique elements](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to accomplish, but it looks like you probably want to yield tuples rather than sets. Edit: Welp, I just realized that you *thought* you were yielding tuples all along. Curly braces `{1,2}` make a set, while parentheses `(1,2)` make a tuple.

Comment: @Aran-Fey: Yup, that was the problem. The "only {'c', 2}` gets swapped" was a red herring. `{0, 'a'}` is also a set and could have been swapped, it just didn't happen in my tests.

Comment: yield a dict instead a collection. collections are unordered (no warranted order).

Comment: @FelixMartinez: Apparently worse than just no _warranted_  order, it's not even _consistent_ across runs. But this was indeed a case of "off-topic, simple typo". The intent was very much not to sort the outputs. It's basically a generator equivalent to `zip(range(len(inp)), inp)`